# Changes in Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

This a probably a very stupid question; so forgive me if I am totally out off-topic and, if this is the case, please delete this post.

Yesterday, I had a vague feeling that things changed on the site. They can be very subtle (may be fonts, sizes, ...) but, being almost blind, I cannot identify the changes.

Could you tell me what has been changing ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20047/18398

Comment: I can confirm certain changes were made. For example, some black fonts were changed to gray, and the quote environment on main changed from gray to yellow. On the other hand, the site seems to be working faster.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; the announcement thread does not explain what has actually changed, only those changes that caused user dissatisfaction are stated there.

Comment: Tank you very much.

Comment: I don't like it for reasons that I probably won't just become comfortable with. It is definitely harder on the eyes now that everything is so soft coloured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a very incomplete list of changes on the *main* site. Feel free to expand (Wayback Machine has old snapshots of the site).

- Main text (body of posts): color changed from dark grey RGB(17,17,17) to slightly lighter  grey RGB(34,34,34). It is still Georgia 15px.
- The color of font in comments went in the opposite direction: from RGB(68,68,68) to RGB(34,34,34).
- Related/linked questions and system links such as "edited" and name of author: went from blue RGB(31,130,167) to much darker blue RGB(0,59,82).
- User reputation, as seen on the front page and question page: de-emphasized from bold RGB(11,54,70) to normal weight RGB(119,119,119).
- Question score, as seen on frontpage: reduced in size from 22px to 17px.
- Post score on the question page: de-emphasized from bold RGB(51,51,51) to normal weight RGB(119,119,119). Here it is, with voting arrows:

Before       [image: before]       and after:         [image: after]

- Sidebar statistics "asked", "active", "viewed" were similarly greyed out to RGB(119,119,119).
- The font of options "share" "flag" etc under a post changed from sans-serif (Helvetica Neue) to serif (Georgia).

Comment: Many thanks for all details !